# When clicking on referenced JIRA-ticket in Gitlab, the URL is wrong

Tags: jira, gitlab

I am trying to integrate Gitlab EE with JIRA as documented at http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/project_services/jira.html.

I created a JIRA-ticket *ABC-1234*, and when I commit with the message *ABC-1234: Blabla* I get the *ABC-1234* part underlined and a link offered in gitlab. But when I click on this link, I get directed to *...[jira]/browse/ABC* instead of *...[jira]/browse/ABC-1234*.

My settings are:

- Project url:    hxttp://[jira]/issues/?jql=project=ABC
- Issues url:     htxtp://[jira]/browse/:id

(The x is there because I cannot post links yet) When I try the links in my browser, they all work fine. Also the issue overview works. Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as easy as changing the service template!